# how to check type of an object in titanium

Tags: types, titanium

I am working with TableViewRow and i need to fire swipe event. TableViewRow doesn't register itself with Swipe event. So, basically i wrapped all my content in a Container View and added it to TableViewRow. Also, i attached swipe event listner to it. And fortunately it is working.
But, i need to pass the current TableViewRow to some function from Swipe event. So, i wrote this code:

```
var tableViewRow = e.source.parent;
while(e.source.parent !=  TiUITableViewRow){
    tableViewRow = tableViewRow.parent;
}
```

It throw the error that TiUITableViewRow variable not found. I even tried javascript typeOf function. Please suggest how to check the type of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is to just set a property on the row and check for that property

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    _type = "row"
});
```

in the eventListener

```
var tableViewRow = e.source.parent;
while(e.source.parent._type !=  "row"){
    tableViewRow = tableViewRow.parent;
}
```

Comment: I think this should work. I will check it out at night and shall respond. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the event return property `row`.

```
var tableViewRow = e.source.parent;
while(e.source.parent !=  e.row){
    tableViewRow = tableViewRow.parent;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain this a bit more. Like, what does this "row" property does.... just to remind you, Swipe event would fire upon the container view and not tableViewRow. Thanks for the efforts.